# VisualRecognitionV3 - NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: swift, watson, visual-recognition

After migrating to Swift 3.1, VisualRecognitionV3 seems to return this error when searching for similar images:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Any thoughts? Couldn't find anything similar anywhere in regards to `.findSimilarImages`.

Comment: Would there be a reason this would occur in Swift 3.1 - but in Swift 3 it would properly deserialize the result?

Comment: There could be a reason why what was previously subscriptable as AnyObject is now not subscriptable because it's Any instead of AnyObject - but I don't see any reason for this NSCocoaErrorDomain error to come up because of the Swift version. This error is because the JSON is invalid: it's unrelated to the code. *Maybe* you also have updated other parts of the code (network?) and accidentally added a new bug and now you don't get (the same) content as before?